# Listeners in TestNG

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

When i write some script of IExecutionListener in maven project, it showing error that remove @Override. But when i write the same script in normal java project, it not showing errors. I don't know what is the problem. Is there any mistake in dependencies in pom.xml file? can some one pls share the best link for listeners also, because it's different in different sites. My code is:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.testng;

import org.testng.IExecutionListener;

public class ExecutionListener1 implements IExecutionListener {
    private long startTime;

    @Override
    public void onExecutionStart() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("TestNG is going to start");     
    }

    @Override
    public void onExecutionFinish() {
        System.out.println("TestNG has finished, took around " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
    }
}
```

And the dependencies i added are:

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.47.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-testng-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: You said: "But when i write the same script in normal java project". But what is a "normal java project"? By default, the compiler Maven plugin is using Java5 as source and target.

Comment: That means when I created a new project in eclipse, I have taken a java project instead of maven project.

Comment: Ok. But you have to configure the compiler plugin with maven. Otherwise you won't be able to use java 6 features. BTW, TestNG only support java 7 with its last releases.